# Rails and Bootstrap 3. Class .col-xs-* and other responsive tools are not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using gem `twitter-bootstrap-rails` and branch `bootstrap3` in order to integrate `bootstrap` in my Rails 4.1 app.

I am installing appropriate gems:

```
gem "therubyracer"
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'http://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git', branch: 'bootstrap3'
```

`bundle install` and

```
rails generate bootstrap:install less
```

And Include `bootstrap_and_overrides.less` in my application.css.

But for some reasons responsive classes like `col-xs-*` are not working (As far as I know Bootstrap3 is responsive out of the box).

`gem list` shows that I have bootstrap version 3.

I have tried to `@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive-utilities";`, `@import 'twitter/bootstrap/responsive'`, `@import 'bootstrap-responsive'`, but reponsive classes are not working.

Also I can't understand how to integrate `.omb_login` class from [login-bootsnippet](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-login-with-social-buttons) in my application. Is it default bootstrap class or it is custom?

I have also tried gem `bootstrap-sass` and instalation without gems. But it still is not working.

Could you help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm whether all the bootstrap classes are not working or is it only the col-xs-* ones which are not working?

Comment: col-xm-* is not working, as well as styles from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/
And my rubymine know nothing about this classes.

Comment: `bootstrap-sass` is the official gem and the one you ought to use.

Comment: Try [bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass). After doing bundle install you'll have to do @import "bootstrap"; in your application.css.scss and //= require bootstrap in your application.js file

Comment: I have tried. Everything is working, but this responsive classes (col-xs-\*).